# Creating a named reply destination for request/response using Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have two separate applications running either side of an ActiveMQ broker; application 1 sends synchronous requests to application 2 which returns the response back to application 1. At present the replies are via temporary queues and I am now trying to create a named reply destination to avoid the overhead of creating multiple temporary queues.

**Application 1**

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel", replyChannel = "responseChannel")
    public OrderDto fetchOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outgoingRequestFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel")
                           .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                                      .requestDestination("request.queue")
                                      .replyDestination("response.topic")
                                      .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"))
                           .channel("responseChannel")
                           .get();
}
```

**Application 2**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingRequestFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                                    .destination("request.queue")
                                    .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID"))
                           .channel("requestChannel")
                           .handle("requestServiceActivator", "handleRequest")
                           .channel("responseChannel")
                           .get();
}

@Component
public class OrderServiceActivator {

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

    @ServiceActivator
    public OrderDto fetchOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {

        return orderService.getById(orderRequest.getId());
    }
}
```

When I start both applications `request.queue` gets created and has one consumer (application 2). `response.topic` gets created but for some reason it has no consumers. Consequently when I send a request in to application 1 it reaches application 2, but after 5 seconds application 1 does not receive a reply and times out and the following errors are logged:

**Application 2**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:/application-2.responseChannel'
```

**Application 1**

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 5000ms
```

I presume I've made some simple configuration error, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your configuration, there is no long-lived consumer for the reply queue - a consumer is created for each request (with a message selector for the specific correlation id).

If you add `.replyContainer()` there will be a permanent consumer.

However, it should make no difference functionally.

I just ran tests similar to yours with and without `replyContainer()` and it all worked fine for me...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutboundGatewayFlow() {
    return f -> f.handleWithAdapter(a ->
            a.jmsGateway(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
//                  .replyContainer()
                    .replyDestination("pipereplies")
                    .correlationKey("JmsCorrelationID")
                    .requestDestination("jmsPipelineTest"));
}
```

I suggest you turn on debug logging to see if that sheds some light.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundGatewayFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from((MessagingGateways g) ->
            g.jms(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                    .correlationKey("JmsCorrelationID")
                    .destination("jmsPipelineTest"))
            .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Gary, I have changed my code to match yours and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm failing to find how the @ServiceActivator is getting wired...

Usually it's something like:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel", outputChannel = "responseChannel")
public .....
```

Perhaps that is what you are missing.

Comment: It is getting wired via `.handle("requestServiceActivator", "handleRequest")` within `incomingRequestFlow`